# How to persist selection of foreign key in related table

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a database design that I need to get some help with

Suppose I have three tables, namely preferences, books, genres. The tables are related as follows:

[image: Database diagram]

The following tables are accessible in a view, in which the user is allowed to add a book to his personal page.

Currently, the view dictates that the user first choose a genre, before he gets the opportunity to select a book (A basic filter).

However, imagine that the user has selected a genre and decides to come back to select a book at a later point - Then this architecture doesn't support that the selected genre is saved as a part of the preferences. Meaning that, even though the user saved his preferences with a genre, he will have to, once he gets back to add his book, select the genre again in order to then select the book.

Therefore, how would I optimally "refactor" this architecture in order to support what I want to achieve.

My first intuition would be to add one more column to the preferences table named "genres_Id" and have a foreign key pointing to the genres table. I guess this is not good practice though..

Comment: A user can only have 1 prefered book ? How do you link the preference with the user ?
A book can only fit one genres ? I would expect that some book fits in more then one genres...

Comment: It seems you have limitation comming from the app code. Are you allowed to get this code change ? If so, please specify what you how you would like the app to behave.
If the preference is a book, then do not allow a user to save after selecting the genre. Force him to select the book. If you want the genre to be saved as part of the preference, then it's part of the preference and could be store in the table as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have something like this, as unusual as it may seem.

```
user {USR}
  PK {USR}

genre {GNR}
   PK {GNR}

book {BOK, GNR}
  PK {BOK}
  FK {GNR} REFERENCES genre {GNR}

preference {USR, BOK}
        PK {USR}
       FK1 {USR} REFERENCES user {USR}
       FK2 {BOK} REFERENCES book {BOK}
```

---

For the stated requirement:

```
user {USR}
  PK {USR}


genre {GNR}
   PK {GNR}


book {BOK, GNR}
  PK {BOK}
  SK {BOK, GNR}

  FK {GNR} REFERENCES genre {GNR}


pref_genre {USR, GNR}
        PK {USR}
        SK {USR, GNR}

       FK1 {USR} REFERENCES user  {USR}
       FK2 {GNR} REFERENCES genre {GNR}


pref_book {USR, BOK, GNR}
       PK {USR}

      FK1 {USR, GNR} REFERENCES pref_genre {USR, GNR}
      FK2 {BOK, GNR} REFERENCES book       {BOK, GNR}
```

And if you want to allow more than one preference for each user, just change keys on `pref_`:

```
pref_genre {USR, GNR}
        PK {USR, GNR}

       FK1 {USR} REFERENCES user  {USR}
       FK2 {GNR} REFERENCES genre {GNR}


pref_book {USR, BOK, GNR}
       PK {USR, BOK}

      FK1 {USR, GNR} REFERENCES pref_genre {USR, GNR}
      FK2 {BOK, GNR} REFERENCES book       {BOK, GNR}
```

---

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```